# ConnectFailure with HttpRequest in Xamarin

Tags: web-services, connection, xamarin, httprequest, xamarin-studio

I'm using the free version of Xamarin Studio to do some test. In aprticular I'm trying to connect to web Service but I receive the ConnectFailure (Network unreachable) when I debug the application.
This is my code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Our code will go here
        // Get our UI controls from the loaded layout
        EditText phoneNumberText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        Button callButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

        // Disable the "Call" button
        callButton.Enabled = false;

        // Add code to translate number
        string translatedNumber = string.Empty;


                    var rxcui = "198440";
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/RxTerms/rxcui/{0}/allinfo", rxcui));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content)) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                }
                else {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                }

                //Assert.NotNull(content);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

}

I don't understand if this is an error caused by the free version or it's me.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is this an Android app?  Does your manifest contain the Internet Permissions setting?

Comment: Yep, make sure you app has Internet permission and also try it on a real device. Some emulator images have problem with network. Also, what Xamarin version you are using? Stable or other?